# Добавить пост на модерацию по условию

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, wp-plugin

Как в WordPress сделать, что когда пользователь пишет статью и если там есть определенные слова или ссылки, то нужно сначала пройти модерацию?

Мб есть какой то плагин, или фильтры?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо использовать фильтр WordPress `save_post`, который срабатывает при сохранении поста.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_post_action' );
function save_post_action( $post_id ) {

    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    if ( 'pending' === $post->post_status ) {
        return;
    }

    $content = $post->post_content;

    if ( ! check_content( $content ) ) {
        // Удаляем хук, чтобы не было зацикливания
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'save_post_action' );

        // Обновляем запись. В это время срабатывает событие save_post
        wp_update_post(
            array(
                'ID'          => $post_id,
                'post_status' => 'pending',
            )
        );

        // Ставим хук обратно
        add_action( 'save_post', 'save_post_action' );
    }
}
```

В примере предполагается, что у вас есть функция check_content(), которая возвращает true или false в зависимости от содержания поста (слова или ссылки в вопросе).